# Java,How to link menu and read file?

Tags: java

below are my code, i try to let useer input the file name but it keep telling me can't found the txt. file, but if i using 
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("C:\Users\k3llvin\workspace\Programming02\bin\assignment02\sample-logfile1.txt"));
it work fine.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,FileNotFoundException
   {

     String time,uniqueName,inventory,softwareUpdate,policy;

     try {
         Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Input the filename:");
         String filename = fileInput.nextLine();
         File inputFile = new File(filename);
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
            /*Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\k3llvin\\workspace\\Programming02\\bin\\assignment02\\sample-logfile1.txt"));*/

         for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            {
                time = fileInput.next();
                uniqueName = fileInput.next();
                inventory = fileInput.next();
                policy = fileInput.next();
                softwareUpdate = fileInput.next();


                Readfile thefile = new Readfile(time,uniqueName,inventory, policy,softwareUpdate);

                System.out.println(thefile);    
            }
            fileInput.close();

     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to locate the sample-logfile1.txt file for opening.");

        } catch (Exception otherExc) {
            // This could occur due to any "unchecked" exceptions occurring, such as incorrect data interpretation during reading.
            System.out.println("An unexpected error has occurred. Details for programmer:");
            otherExc.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the File inputFile, you are just giving the constructor a string, the constructor needs the path to the file. That is why when you hard type in the file path it works.

try changing it to

```
String filename = fileInput.nextLine();
File inputFile = new File(filename);
inputFile=inputFile.getAbsolutePath();
Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
```